# Your binary does not support iPad Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad

I have made a phonegap app and when I am trying to deploy it on App store I get this error

> Your binary does not support iPad. The screenshots or app video preview for iPad won’t be shown on the App Store

I have googled it and not found anything specific. Is it a phonegap thing that I have to somehow try and fix or is related to app store?

Anyone else have this error?

Comment: do you have iPad support in your app?

Comment: Do I have to specify it is my config file somewhere about ipad? Like for android I only specified it once and then it works on tablets and smartphones. I can attact my config file for you to have a look.

Comment: yes that means your app does not support iPad resolution, you have work on your screen to resize for those resolution or you have to create alternate screens to work on iPad.

Comment: Can I get a link to some document which I have to follow or something?

Comment: in your config.xml check if you have `<preference name="target-device" value="handset" />` and remove because this will only build for iPhone

Comment: yes I have that in my config file, after removing it do I have to add something else? Like universal or something?

Comment: Adding this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this [PhoneGap Preferences](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html)

by default all builds are universal so if you have `<preference name="target-device" value="handset" />` in your config.xml either remove it or set it as `<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />` to add iPad support